# Why does nansum work for input that exceeds matrix dimensions?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, dimensions

I am wondering about matlab's `nansum`function.

When I use the example [from the documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/nansum.html)

```
X = magic(3);
X([1 6:9]) = repmat(NaN, 1, 5);

X =

   NaN     1   NaN
     3     5   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN
```

and then call

```
>> nansum(X, 1)

ans =

     7     6     0

>> nansum(X, 2)

ans =

     1
     8
     4
```

it works as expected.

However, what I did not expect is that it also works for

```
>> nansum(X, 400)

ans =

     0     1     0
     3     5     0
     4     0     0
```

What is the reasoning here? Why wouldn't this crash with the error that `dim`exceeds the matrix dimensions?

Comment: Irrelevant to your question: you don't need repmat at right hand to match number of elements at the left hand. X([1 6:9]) = NaN simply works.

Comment: @XiangruiLi: I just blindly copied this from the documentation :) Thanks for the comment, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MATLAB, all arrays/matrices have infinite singleton trailing dimensions.

A singleton dimension is a dimension, `dim`, where `size(A,dim) = 1`. It's called a trailing singleton dimension when it comes after all non-singleton dimensions (i.e. it doesn't change the structure of the matrix).

Any function (including `nansum`) which can operate on a specific dimension can do so on any one of the infinite singleton dimensions. Often you wont see any affect (for instance using `max` or `sum` in this way simply returns the inputs<sup>[1]</sup>), but `nansum` replaces `NaN` with zero, so that's all that happens.

**Note that `nansum(A,dim)` is the same as `sum(A,dim,'omitnan')`**. You can see this by typing `edit nansum`. So my example uses `sum` for ease. See the bottom of this answer for references about defined behaviour.

Let's try to visualise this:

```
A = ones(3,4);
size( A ) % >> ans = [3, 4]
% Under the hood:
% size( A ) = [3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
sum( A, 1 )   % Sum through the rows, or the 1st dimension, which has 3 elements per sum
              % >> ans = [3 3 3 3]
sum( A, 2 )   % Sum through the columns, or the 2nd dimension, which has 4 elements per sum
              % >> ans = [4; 4; 4]
sum( A, 400 ) % Sum through the ???, the 400th dimension, which has 1 element per sum
              % >> ans = [1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1]
```

If you wanted, you could `reshape` the original matrix to have singleton 2nd through 399th dimensions to further this:

```
% Set up dimensions as [3, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 4], for a 400-D array!
dims = num2cell( [3 ones(1,398), 4] );
% Note we'll now still have trailing singleton dims, but have 398 in the structure too
B = reshape( A, dims{:} );
```

Now we can do a similar `sum` example. The final thing to know is that `squeeze` removes non-trailing singleton dimensions, we can use this to tidy up the outputs:

```
sum( B, 1 ); % >> ans(:,:,1,1,1,...,1) = 3 
             % >> ans(:,:,1,1,1,...,2) = 3
             % >> ans(:,:,1,1,1,...,3) = 3
             % >> ans(:,:,1,1,1,...,4) = 3
squeeze( sum( B, 1 ) ); % >> ans = [3; 3; 3; 3] 

% similarly  
squeeze( sum( B, 2 ) );   % >> ans = [1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1]
squeeze( sum( B, 400 ) ); % >> ans = [4; 4; 4]
```

We can see that, now we've reshaped things, summing in the 400th dimension does the same as originally summing in the 2nd dimension and vice-versa. This would be easier to visualise if you replaced 400 with 3!

---

[ **1** ] See the [`sum`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#btv6ok6-3) and [`max`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html?#bubhhu5-1-dim) documentation as examples where the behaviour is explicitly defined "if dim is greater than `ndims(A)`." In both cases the implementation is made more efficient by just returning `A`. In the case of `nansum` there has to be some computation in case elements are `NaN`.

Comment: Just to add: the reason this is true is because all matrices are 1D inside. Dimensions are just a higher level construct to generate indexing in MATLAB, but under the hood there is no such thing as a ND matrix, only 1D ones.

Comment: Wizards like @Ander surely only ever use linear indexing because they have a sense of how the elements are ordered for N dimensional matrices under the hood ;) It's a good thing to point out, I hadn't really considered the 1D-ness of everything at all in my answer!

Comment: @Wolfie haha :P Just pointing that out because then it makes more sense. If you think that inside there are C/Fortran type of ND arrays (pointers of pointers of pointers) then its harder to see how there can be 400 dims (*how far do the pointers go?*) but if you know its a higher level construct, and ultimately its all 1D, then its easier to see why this applies. Also, this is why for big matrices, adding column-wise or row-wise have different performance. One of them reads adjacent memory and the other needs to jump in a 1D array. But im diverging from the topic now....

Answer (score 2):

The matrix does have a 400th dimension. It is 1. So when you sum in this dimension it just returns the matrix you give as input with the `NaN`s omitted / counted at 0.

It is the same with standard `sum`

```
>>A = magic(3)

A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>>sum(A,400)

ans =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

**EDIT:** A maybe better example is

```
A = 5;
```

This variable have `size(A)=[1,1];` in other words the size of dimension 1 is `1` just as its 400th dimension, but it still makes sense to sum

```
sum(A)

ans =

     5
```

Comment: But that's exactly the confusing part: If there is no 400th dimension, it should just crash; same holds for `sum`.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a maybe better example.

Comment: Ok, it remains counter intuitive (having a `numpy` background), but then I just have to live with that :) (I wait for a while with acceptance to see if something else shows up...)

Comment: Depends on how you think about it. If you just consider a single number, what is the dimension of that number? Well it can be thought of as a scalar, thus sum does not makes sense, it can be a vector of length 1, thus sum does makes sense (this is numpy), it can be a matrix of dimension 1x1 or it can be some tensor with dimension 1x1x1x...x1, which is what matlab thinks of it as which makes sum in all dimensions to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix doesn't have a 400th dimension (better, it has infinite implicit singleton dimension), simply the implementation of sum return the matrix when the dim input exceeds the matrix dimension as the documentation of sum says:

*sum returns A when dim is greater than ndims(A) or when size(A,dim) is 1*

https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#btv6ok6-3

Comment: sorry but the output when he call nansum with 400 return the matrix with zero instead of NaN, not the nansum. In terms of performance, why compute a sum when you can just return the matrix?

Comment: That is the same thing, the `nansum` is 0 when all elements in the sum are `NaN`. I don't get what you're trying to say in that comment.